# Newton mail client and end-to-end encryption

Tags: email, encryption, imap, setup, email-client

I am not an expert in emails, but I was wondering if it was possible to use your favorite email client on desktop and mobile (for example [Newton](https://newtonhq.com/) or [Polymail](https://polymail.io/)) and connect it with IMAP to an end-to-end encripted mail service.

For example I tried to use my Protonmail account with Newton (yes, I tried with Proton Bridge) but I had no luck.

What I see is that a lot of encrypted email providers (like [securemymail](https://www.securemyemail.com), [Protonmail](https://protonmail.com/) or [Tutanota](https://tutanota.com)) give you their own email client. Are IMAP client and end to end encrypton incompatible?

Has anyone a good idea of how to do the setup I am imagining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email client you'd like to use needs to be able to speak you provider's encryption. If we're simply talking GPG encryption, that's easy.

For (as you mentioned them) Protonmail, you'll need said Proton Bridge to make your client encryption aware (or rather: agnostic).

It all depends on the service you'd like to use and what their on-top security tool/toolchain is.